# Determining if a list of numbers is in heap order, Python 3.2

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, heap, python-3.2

I just discovered heap (in real life and in Python) and now I'm trying to determine if a certain list of random numbers is in heap order.
Problem is I'm not sure myself if I actually understand "heap" in practice even though I believe the definition provided makes sense.

I found some practice problems that should help you write heap psuedo code.
This is the problem and below it is my attempt at solving it:

Write a function that checks whether a list of numbers is a heap or not:

Given a list, it returns True if the numbers are in a heap order, and False if the numbers are not and have the programme return and print the answer.

Example:

- returns True:
  the following list is in heap order: [0,1, 10, 2, 3, 11, 12, 4, 5, 19, 15]
- returns False
  the following list is not in heap order: [0, 1, 10, 2, 15, 11, 12, 4, 5, 19, 3]

Then there were 2 lists with a bunch of random numbers from 1 - 100 thrown in there, and some repeat.

```
    def heap_or(A):
      n = len(A)
      for i in range(n):
        start = (len(A) - 2) / 2
        while start >= 0:
          siftDown(A, start, len(A) - 1)
          start -= 1:
             return 'True'
        else:
             return 'False'

    def siftDown(A, start, end):
    root = start
    while root * 2 + 1 <= end:
        number = root * 2 + 1
        if number + 1 <= end and A[number] < A[number + 1]:
            number += 1
        if number <= end and A[root] < A[number]:
            A[root], A[number] = A[number], A[root]
            root = number
        else:
            return

     print
```

Can somebody please give me a hand?  Because I'm not really sure if I'm defining heap correctly the code is giving me a hard time as well!

Comment: We can give you a hand but you should include your implementation of `siftDown` as well

Comment: @jamylak I'm almost positive it's not correct because I was trying to model my after someone else's heap ordering for min/max but I'll add it to my original post anyways now!

Comment: @jamylak - so do you think you'll be able to help me out now?

Comment: And here I though a heap was a tree-structure.

Comment: related: [`heapq` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heap property (for a max heap) is that each node should be greater than or equal to its parent.  The parent of element `i` in a binary heap stored in an array is element `(i - 1) // 2`:

```
def is_heap(A):
    return all(A[i] >= A[(i - 1) // 2] for i in range(1, len(A)))
```

Obviously because the heap is stored in array we don't need to check the shape.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I'm not looking for the max heap tho - does it matter?  So, say I have one of the above mentioned lists, or any other one, how would I address that?

        `A = [1,2,4,5,3,2,5,2]
        def is_heap(A):
          return all(A[i] >= A[(i - 1) // 2] for i in range(1, len(A)))`

And more importantly, how would I get it to show me the answer, True or False? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2227808 you must have *some* comparison function in mind; if that's `>=` then you have a max heap.  If you really want a string as the result, just use `str`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer! I think I'm just confused as to where I should I put my print function so the Python interpreter tells me if it's True or False.  I tried putting it before return all and adding an extra pair of parentheses but that returned an "invalid synthax".

Comment: Never mind, figured it out, silly question!  Thanks again for helping out!